# Difference between Python's "import X" and "from module import X"?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Google App Engine just gave me an error I don't understand. Given a module "X" that contains the file "Car.py" which contains a class "Car",

and given this block of code:

```
import X 

class Passenger(db.Model):
  car = db.ReferenceProperty(X.Car.Car)
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Car'
```

But if I change it to:

```
from X import Car

class Passenger(db.Model):
  car = db.ReferenceProperty(Car.Car)
```

It works. They look the same to me, but they're clearly not. What's the difference?

Comment: X is not a module here, it's a package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Lattyware points out, `X` is a package, and that's just the way packages work. Importing the outer level doesn't automatically give you access to the modules within it. You could do `import X.Car` if you wanted to refer to the whole thing as `X.Car.Car`.

(Also please note Python is not Java: there's no reason to have each class in a separate file, and even if you do then modules and packages usually have lower case names.)

Comment: Thanks, Daniel -- I'm new to Python and this is helpful. I'm used to keeping classes into their own files but the syntax *is* super-clunky that way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that when the package X is loaded, it contains modules but they are not in it's namespace.

To put the module into the package's namespace, add `import module` (where `module` is the name of the module, naturally) into the `__init__.py` file for the package. It will then be in the package's namespace, and you can use the first way of accessing Car.

Comment: Thanks, Lattyware; as mentioned to Daniel, I'm new to Python and clearly don't have the nomenclature down yet. I did find that trick of using __init__.py to import each module, though, and that's been helpful.